How to load all tables from a specific schema in on-premise database to Tables section of the lakehouse in fabric using pipeline?
I am trying to ingest data from on-premise database to fabric lakehouse using pipeline. First, I created script activity to get a list of all table names using  SELECT table_name FROM all_tables WHERE owner = 'SCHEMA1'. In pipeline run, I am getting output like this,
{
    "resultSetCount": 1,
    "recordsAffected": 0,
    "resultSets": [
        {
            "rowCount": 2637,
            "rows": [
                {
                    "TABLE_NAME": "Table1"
                },
                {
                    "TABLE_NAME": "Table2"
                },.....

I want to convert this to an array of table names which I can pass to foreach activity to iterate through and use copydata activity inside foreach to land data into lakehouse. Also, I want to filter tablenames inside foreach in order to get only desired tables for further engineering work.
I am connecting all pipeline components by providing references in dynamic content only.
One approach I tried is setting a variable in the pipeline. But it is not working when I pass this variable to foreach. It is passing an empty dictionary at this point. Description is below.
Pipeline Run:
set_variable input is
{
    "variableName": "RawTableNames",
    "value": [
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Table1"
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Table2"
        },.....

set_variable output is
{
    "name": "RawTableNames",
    "value": [
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Table1"
        },
        {
            "TABLE_NAME": "Table2"
        },.....

foreach input is
{
    "ItemsCount": "2637"
} 

My expectations:
In the input of foreach, if I get a list of tablenames, it can be iterated by foreach for next tasks.


In the input of foreach, if I get a list of tablenames, it can be iterated by foreach for next tasks

For-each activity doesn't give the provided array in its output or input. In input, it will show the count of the array that you have given like { "ItemsCount": "3" }, and it will show the empty object in the output.

You can use the activities that you want inside For-each activity.

It will work as per the iterations.

I am trying to ingest data from on-premise database to fabric lakehouse using pipeline

To filter the table names, you can use ADF pipeline dynamic expressions in an if activity. Make a condition in the if activity expression and you can proceed with copy activity in the True activities of if. If the current Table name @item().TABLE_NAME satisfies your condition in the if activity, it will execute the copy activity in the True activities, otherwise it will execute the activities in the False activities of If. You can have any activities in the False activities if you want or you can leave empty as per your requirement.
You need to parameterize the datasets in the copy activity source and sink to pass the current table name @item().TABLE_NAME in each iteration.
You can go through this SO answer to know more about the dataset parameters and passing values to those.
The For-each activity won't have any output. If you want to get the filtered table names array, you need to build the array inside for-each after checking condition using append variable activity. Or you can use Filter activity on the input array after for-each activity.

According to your suggestion, I used set variable inside foreach and is giving me output like
{
"name": "table_name",
"value": "TABLE1"
}
While I try to pass this to if statement using @contains(variables('Required_Tables'), variables('table_name')) to compare and get desired tables loaded, it is getting input as empty set. {}
Required_Tables is a set variable defined outside foreach in the pipeline which contains value as ["TABLE1", "TABLE2"] making pipeline structure: Lookup -> set_variable (req tables) -> foreach (set_variable -> if statement (T: copydata, F: nothing))

The if activity also won't give any input or output values. You need to cross check the expression based on the execution of the activities either True or false activities. What activities are running in your case?

It is working now. It seems like I was using set variable without any purpose which was causing trouble. Thanks for the help and sorry for delaying in response.
